# cant sent data from opera browser using HttpRequest

Tags: opera, httprequest

I can sent data to server using HttpRequest from all browser apart from opera browser. I tired opera 11.61 too. But still i cant sent data to server from opera browser.My code is

```
xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
var url="http://localhost";
xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=binny";
function timerMethod() 
{
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlHttp.send(params);
}
```

Please help me in this issue

With Regards,
Muthu.S

Comment: I think we need to see some more of the code. Especially, where is timerMethod() called from? Are there any console errors? This code is also running on a http://localhost page, right?

Answer (score 0):

This should work provided you call `timerMethod()` from elsewhere in the code as hallvors alluded to. For example:

```
xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
var url="http://localhost/stackoverflow/response.php";
xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=binny";
function timerMethod()
{
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    xmlHttp.send(params);

    xmlHttp.onload = function(){
        console.log( this.responseText );
    }
}

timerMethod();
```